# Uploading image with Ionic/angular to php script does not work

Tags: php, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, image-uploading

I am trying to make my Ionic app upload an image that was selected by the user. I read several tutorials, however i didn't manage to make it work. I want the app to run in the browser, therefore I didn't implement a solution running on mobile platforms only.

My angular component sends a post request to a server where the following php-script is hosted and an "uploads" folder is created as specified. But everytime I want to upload my file I get the  "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!" message specified in my PHP-Script.

I think I might be send the data in the wrong format, however could figure out what to do.

Any ideas what my problem could be?

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $data = ['success' => true, 'message' => 'Upload and move success'];
    echo json_encode( $data );
} else{
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $data = ['success' => false, 'message' => 'There was an error uploading the file, please try again!'];
    echo json_encode( $data );
}

?>
```

And here is my Typescript code in my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-erledigt-modal',
  templateUrl: './erledigt-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./erledigt-modal.component.scss'],
})
export class ErledigtModalComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  selectedFile = null;

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onFileChanged(event) {
      this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0]
  }

  onUpload() {

    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.http.post('https://...MyAPI.../upload.php', uploadData).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }


}
```

I also tried the following POST-request without success:

```
this.http.post('https://...MyAPI.../upload.php', this.selectedFile).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
});
  }
```

My HTML looks simply like this:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)">
<button type="button" (click)="onUpload()">Upload</button>
```

Comment: does your api even work? did you try to call the api and return a simple int value for example?

Comment: It sends me the "'There was an error uploading the file, please try again!" message, which is in the PHP Code, so that should be the proof that it works, right?

Comment: yes youre right, do you have the right permission to write the file on the server ? www-data needs the permission to write a file to your filesystem. ssh on your server and try „chown -R www-data:www-data uploads“

Comment: I tried with a solution that only works on mobile devices before (see https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/ ) and it worked, so I guess I do have the right permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution....

`if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path))`

and

```
uploadData.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
```

do not work together because the name I used in the formdata is 'image' and the PHP script expects 'file'.. so changing 'image' to 'file' was the solution...